# Disable button while file upload is in progress ipywidgets

Tags: python, jupyter, ipywidgets

I have a Jupyter Notebook application, which uses Voila and ipywidget for a simple UI page. As part of the process, I need to upload a file using FileUpload widget. The file size is in the range of 50-80 MBs, so it takes some time for the file to get uploaded.

What I want to do is, when the file upload is in progress (takes 8-10 seconds), the submit button should be disabled, so that user doesn't get confused and doesn't end up clicking button twice.

I do have the code for disabling the button in on_click method, but the issue is, the callback method is only invoked when the file has been uploaded, and therefore disabling the button after that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't know enough about the inner workings to see how to implement it in conjunction with uploading widget, but since this would being occuring in presumably an event loop, I suspect based on discussions I've seen that this should somehow involve asyncio, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/threading-with-matplotlib-and-ipywidgets/14674/2?u=fomightez) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/is-it-possible-to-get-the-current-value-of-a-widget-slider-from-a-function-without-using-multithreading/15524/2?u=fomightez).